# Update url when change slide

Tags: url, slide

I installed this cool demo http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/06/26/draggable-dual-view-slideshow/ on this website http://wedding.halocommunication.com

What I try to do, with no success, is to update url (like in this site wild.as) when a slide changes.

This demo use dragdealer plugin skidding.github.io/dragdealer

One of my experiment was to add this line at the end of this function, but generates errors

`/**
     * DragDealer plugin callback: update current value
     */
    DragSlideshow.prototype._navigate = function( x, y ) {
        // add class "current" to the current slide / remove that same class from the old current slide
        classie.remove( this.slides[ this.current || 0 ], 'current' );
        this.current = this.dd.getStep()[0] - 1;
        classie.add( this.slides[ this.current ], 'current' );
        window.location.href = 'http://test.com/' + this.slides.attr('data-content');
    }`

Anyone could help me with some hints?
Thank you